# How do you make a tableview within a vbox grow inside a borderpane using Javafx Scene Builder?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

In first screenshot you can see tableview is positioned correctly.  In second screenshot when app is resized to max size the tableview doesn't grow to fill in gap from the bottom of the table to the bottom of the pane.  How do I fill in that gap?  I set the max height to max for all the elements already.  Not sure what else to do.

[image]

[image]

[image]

customer.fxml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Region?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gci.controllers.CustomerController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" styleClass="back-white" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <VBox layoutX="32.0" layoutY="89.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: orange; -fx-border-color: #003366;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="75.0">
               <children>
                  <HBox spacing="10.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
                     <children>
                        <Button fx:id="addButton" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleAddButton" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="85.0" text="Add">
                           <graphic>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="20.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@../assets/images/add.png" />
                                 </image>
                              </ImageView>
                           </graphic>
                           <styleClass>
                              <String fx:value="hover-hand" />
                              <String fx:value="hover-light-blue" />
                           </styleClass>
                           <effect>
                              <DropShadow height="25.0" offsetX="4.0" offsetY="4.0" radius="12.0" width="25.0" />
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="modifyButton" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleModifyButton" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="85.0" text="Modify">
                           <graphic>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="20.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@../assets/images/edit.png" />
                                 </image>
                              </ImageView>
                           </graphic>
                           <styleClass>
                              <String fx:value="hover-hand" />
                              <String fx:value="hover-light-blue" />
                           </styleClass>
                           <effect>
                              <DropShadow height="25.0" offsetX="4.0" offsetY="4.0" radius="12.0" width="25.0" />
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="deleteButton" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleDeleteButton" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="85.0" text="Delete">
                           <graphic>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="20.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@../assets/images/trash.png" />
                                 </image>
                              </ImageView>
                           </graphic>
                           <styleClass>
                              <String fx:value="hover-hand" />
                              <String fx:value="hover-light-blue" />
                           </styleClass>
                           <effect>
                              <DropShadow height="25.0" offsetX="4.0" offsetY="4.0" radius="12.0" width="25.0" />
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                        <Region prefHeight="10.0" prefWidth="50.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                        <Button fx:id="searchButton" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleSearchButton" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="85.0" text="Search">
                           <graphic>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="20.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@../assets/images/search.png" />
                                 </image>
                              </ImageView>
                           </graphic>
                           <styleClass>
                              <String fx:value="hover-hand" />
                              <String fx:value="hover-light-blue" />
                           </styleClass>
                           <effect>
                              <DropShadow height="25.0" offsetX="4.0" offsetY="4.0" radius="12.0" width="25.0" />
                           </effect>
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <TextField fx:id="searchTextField" promptText="Search by customer name" style="-fx-prompt-text-fill: #88B3D9;" styleClass="back-light-blue" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                           <effect>
                              <DropShadow color="#3c3737" height="25.0" offsetX="4.0" offsetY="4.0" radius="12.0" width="25.0" />
                           </effect>
                        </TextField>
                     </children>
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </HBox>
                  <TableView fx:id="mainTableView" focusTraversable="false" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="528.0" prefWidth="874.0">
                     <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="phoneColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Phone" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="addressColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Address" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="cityColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="City" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="postalColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Postal Code" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="countryColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Country" />
                     </columns>
                     <columnResizePolicy>
                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                     </columnResizePolicy>
                     <effect>
                        <DropShadow blurType="GAUSSIAN" height="25.0" offsetX="4.0" offsetY="4.0" radius="12.0" width="25.0" />
                     </effect>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </VBox>
            <Label id="title" fx:id="titleLabel" layoutX="40.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Customers" textFill="#002e51">
               <font>
                  <Font name="PT Serif Caption" size="36.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
   <stylesheets>
      <URL value="@../assets/stylesheets/app.css" />
      <URL value="@../assets/stylesheets/customer.css" />
   </stylesheets>
</VBox>
```

app.fxml code (borderpane dashboard which applies customer.fxml to centerpane)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<BorderPane fx:id="border_pane" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1200.0" styleClass="back-white" stylesheets="@../assets/stylesheets/app.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gci.controllers.AppController">
   <center>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" styleClass="back-white" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <ImageView fitHeight="400.0" fitWidth="400.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../assets/images/logo%20200.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </children></VBox>
   </center>
   <left>
      <HBox BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <VBox styleClass="back-dark-blue">
               <children>
                  <HBox>
                     <children>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="200.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                           <image>
                              <Image url="@../assets/images/logo%20200.png" />
                           </image>
                        </ImageView>
                     </children>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                     </padding>
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </HBox>
                  <VBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="210.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="10.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Appointments" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                           <styleClass>
                              <String fx:value="back-transparent" />
                              <String fx:value="fill-white" />
                              <String fx:value="fn-18" />
                              <String fx:value="hover-hand" />
                              <String fx:value="hover-light-blue" />
                           </styleClass>
                           <graphic>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="30.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@../assets/images/appt.png" />
                                 </image>
                              </ImageView>
                           </graphic>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                     </padding>
                     <styleClass>
                        <String fx:value="hover-hand" />
                        <String fx:value="hover-light-blue" />
                     </styleClass>
                  </VBox>
                  <VBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="675.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="10.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Calendar" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                           <styleClass>
                              <String fx:value="back-transparent" />
                              <String fx:value="fill-white" />
                              <String fx:value="fn-18" />
                              <String fx:value="hover-hand" />
                              <String fx:value="hover-light-blue" />
                           </styleClass>
                           <graphic>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="30.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@../assets/images/calendar.jpg" />
                                 </image>
                              </ImageView>
                           </graphic>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                     </padding>
                     <styleClass>
                        <String fx:value="hover-hand" />
                        <String fx:value="hover-light-blue" />
                     </styleClass>
                  </VBox>
                  <VBox alignment="CENTER">
                     <children>
                        <Button alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="10.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#show_customers" text="Customers" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                           <styleClass>
                              <String fx:value="back-transparent" />
                              <String fx:value="fill-white" />
                              <String fx:value="fn-18" />
                              <String fx:value="hover-hand" />
                              <String fx:value="hover-light-blue" />
                           </styleClass>
                           <graphic>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="30.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@../assets/images/customers.png" />
                                 </image>
                              </ImageView>
                           </graphic>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                     </padding>
                     <styleClass>
                        <String fx:value="hover-hand" />
                        <String fx:value="hover-light-blue" />
                     </styleClass>
                  </VBox>
                  <VBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="675.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="10.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Reports">
                           <styleClass>
                              <String fx:value="back-transparent" />
                              <String fx:value="fill-white" />
                              <String fx:value="fn-18" />
                              <String fx:value="hover-hand" />
                              <String fx:value="hover-light-blue" />
                           </styleClass>
                           <graphic>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="30.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@../assets/images/report.png" />
                                 </image>
                              </ImageView>
                           </graphic>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                     </padding>
                     <styleClass>
                        <String fx:value="hover-hand" />
                        <String fx:value="hover-light-blue" />
                     </styleClass>
                  </VBox>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </left>
   <bottom>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="copyrightLabel" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="393.0" text="Copyright © 2019 Global Consulting Institution">
               <styleClass>
                  <String fx:value="fill-white" />
                  <String fx:value="fn-14" />
               </styleClass>
            </Label>
         </children>
         <styleClass>
            <String fx:value="back-orange" />
            <String fx:value="fill-white" />
         </styleClass>
      </HBox>
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: You're not anchoring your `VBox` to the bottom of the `AnchorPane` and your `TableView` needs to be set to `VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"`

Comment: TL; DR: please provide mcve.

Comment: @Zephyr I followed your instructions and it worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: In case you are not using <tags> but programatically javafx - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39196085/1461862